# TLS 1.1/1.2 support for Xamarin.Android

Tags: xamarin.android, httpclient, xamarin.forms, tls1.2

Right now I'm developing an application using Xamarin.Forms. I ran into a problem with the TLS protocol.

My application uses an API. Because of security reasons the API uses HTTPS. This week we decided to remove the support of TLS 1.0 to accept only TLS 1.1 and 1.2 on the server side, but after we made this change, I noticed that my application stoped working.

While debugging I noticed that the call of the API throws an exception (I'm using HttpClient class from .Net). By searching for solutions on the Internet, I saw that many people think the problem is related to TLS support.

I solved this problem on Android and iOS using a plugin named [ModernHTTPClient](https://components.xamarin.com/view/modernhttpclient) but one of my customers reported me that on his device running on Android they still have the problem (he's running a device with Android 4.2).

Checking Android documentation I saw that this version have support but is not enable by default, and the hard part is that there's not much documentation in the Internet about how I can activate this.

Any advice of how I can activate this? Did Xamarin.Android have native support for TLS 1.1 and up?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post specific information about the main exception thrown from HttpClient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ModernHTTPClient should use the platforms' native HTTP handling. Looks like for now you can build it manually using this pull: https://github.com/paulcbetts/ModernHttpClient/pull/210

Comment: Thanks Joe, yes this approach fix my problem.

Comment: Also, suggest support for Windows Application.